# Possible to create Oracle Database object types inside of PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to create an object type inside of a package in Oracle Database 10g?  Something like:

```
create or replace package my_package as 
    type my_type as object (
        id number(15) 
     ); 
end;
```

Gives:

> Error(3,9): PLS-00540: object not supported in this context.

What I'm ultimately looking to be able to do is use polymorphism but also allow the objects to access tables and use PL/SQL, which isn't allowed in types defined outside of packages.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: This still doesn't work in oracle 11.2.... This is possible in both Pascal and ADA, ancestors of pl/sql; so I thought we will get there quickly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [Oracle 10g documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i7504):

> Currently, you cannot define object
>   types in a PL/SQL block, subprogram,
>   or package.

So, unfortunately, no.

Comment: It is true that you can't define object types in PL/SQL but you can use PL/SQL in an object body defined outside PL/SQL. jlpp makes a wrong assumptation.

Answer (score 10):

Update for Oracle 11g Release 2:

From [Chapter 3 Using PL/SQL With Object Types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjplsql.htm#CHDEFBEA) of [Oracle Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm):

> Using object types in a PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package is a two-step process.
>
> 1. You must define object types using the SQL statement CREATE TYPE, in SQL*Plus or other similar programs.
>
>    After an object type is defined and installed in the schema, you can use it in any PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package.
> 2. In PL/SQL, you then declare a variable whose data type is the user-defined type or ADT that you just defined.

Comment: The original question is about "creating" objects inside package. Your reply is about "using" objects inside plsql block/packages... It's very different topic.

Answer (score 6):

You can use PL/SQL in objects that are defined outside a PL/SQL package!! Use object bodies:

```
CREATE TYPE person_typ AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
  first_name     VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(25),
  email          VARCHAR2(25),
  phone          VARCHAR2(20),
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER, 
  MEMBER PROCEDURE display_details ( SELF IN OUT NOCOPY person_typ ));
/

CREATE TYPE BODY person_typ AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN idno;
  END;
  MEMBER PROCEDURE display_details ( SELF IN OUT NOCOPY person_typ ) IS
  BEGIN
    -- use the PUT_LINE procedure of the DBMS_OUTPUT package to display details
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(idno) || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || last_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(email || ' '  || phone);
  END;
END;
/
```

copy-pasted this example from this link: http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/support/oracle/doc/10.2/appdev.102/b14260/adobjint.htm

Comment: I know it's 9 years old, but man, this doesn't address the question.