# How to call a package from stored procedure, PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This is my package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE mypak AS

  TYPE something1 IS RECORD (
    x       Date,
    y       VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    z       Number
  );

  TYPE something IS TABLE OF something1;
END mypak;
```

and my stored procedure is:

```
create or replace procedure procedure_name(...) as
a date,
b varchar2,
c varchar2
begin
(...)
end procedure_name;
```

How do I call a package from stored procedure?
I tried "d something1", here, "something1" is defined in mypak package.. but it gave me an error. How do I call this "something1", thats defined in mypak package, into the stored procedure?

```
create or replace procedure procedure_name(...) as
a date,
b varchar2,
c varchar2,
d something1
begin
(...)
end procedure_name;
```

Comment: You shown a package specification. Do you have a package body ?

Comment: Did you look at these?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069176/possible-to-create-oracle-database-object-types-inside-of-pl-sql
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299089/oracle-user-defined-type-inside-package-definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing anything in a package is done with a `.` (period).

```
create or replace procedure procedure_name(
  a date,
  b varchar2,
  c varchar2,
  d mypak.something1) as
begin
  NULL; 
end procedure_name;
```

The identifier `mypak` could be a package or a synonym in the current schema, a public synonym, or it could be another schema's package or synonym.  So `schemaX.package.type` is also valid syntax.

The only time that you do not need to prefix the a type declared in a package is in the same package.  So if mypak declared a procedure or function, that procedure or function could reference `something1` without qualifying it.