# oracle owner type in package: How to use it in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Maybe it is a boring question for you, but I did not find an answer until now.

I defined a Vector Type Record in package. How can I use this in SQL?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_MATH AS 
TYPE VECTOR IS RECORD (
    X NUMBER,
    Y NUMBER,
    Z NUMBER
); 
FUNCTION ARC(A VECTOR, B VECTOR) RETURN NUMBER;
END;
```

How can I use this in SQL

```
SELECT PKG_MATH.ARC(PKG_MATH.VECTOR(1,1,0),PKG_MATH.VECTOR(1,-1,0)) FROM DUAL;
```

If I do this I get

> ORA-06553 PLS-222: no function with name 'VECTOR' exist

Comment: You can't, at least not yet. It would be a nice feature; however, there are some engineering challenges that would need to be solved first (e.g. what happens if you store a `pkg_math.vector()` in a table, and then want to recompile the package, possibly changing the structure of the type?).

Answer (score 1):

You must define the [TYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069176/possible-to-create-oracle-database-object-types-inside-of-pl-sql) in SQL using `CREATE TYPE`

```
CREATE TYPE VECTOR IS OBJECT (
    X NUMBER,
    Y NUMBER,
    Z NUMBER
); 
/
```

Than you can use it in the PACKAGEd function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_MATH AS 
 FUNCTION ARC (A VECTOR, B VECTOR) RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_MATH AS 
 FUNCTION ARC (A VECTOR, B VECTOR) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  return (-1);
END; 
END;
/


select PKG_MATH.ARC(VECTOR(1,1,1), VECTOR(0,90,0)) from dual

PKG_MATH.ARC(VECTOR(1,1,1),VECTOR(0,90,0))
------------------------------------------
                                        -1
```

Comment: is it impossible to bundle this inside the package? Do I need to define it as an object?

Comment: I suppose so. Please recheck the Oracle documentation link I provided.